# LVM problem after upgrade 14.04 - 20.04

Tags: upgrade, 20.04, lvm

I'm trying to upgrade an old ubuntu server (14.04) to latest LTS (20.04). After do-release-upgrade it can't boot because of an error loading LVM. It doesn't use encryption (most posts I found online had to do with that). I tried reinstalling lvm2 in a chroot environment, but that didn't help.
The box has a separate /boot partition with ext2 without lvm.

During install it notified that grub wasn't able to write to /dev/dm-0

It's hard to capture the entire boot logging unfortunately, but it ends with this:

```
lvmetad is not active yet, using direct activation during sysinit
volume group "..." not found
Cannot process volume group "..."


ALERT! /dev/mapper/...-root does not exist. Dropping to a shell!
```

And then I end up in initramfs.

Any ideas what I could do to revive it from here?

Answer (score 1):

I had three problems with LVM after upgrading 18.04 to 20.04:

1. `cryptsetup-initramfs` was deleted, had to re-install it in chroot. Maybe it happened because I have disabled installing recommended and suggested packages, IDK.
2. Volume Group metadata had to be upgraded manually with `vgck --updatemetadata yourvgname`
3. The VG name was somehow changed from `lvm-name` to just `name` and I had to edit `/etc/crypttab` and `update-initramfs -u -k all`.

Reported them here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/bugs/1877473 please mark the issue as affecting you if it is.