# Is it safe to do-release-upgrade Ubuntu Server 16.04.7 to 18.04.5 when root partition is on lvm?

Tags: 16.04, 18.04, lvm, do-release-upgrade

I have an Ubuntu 16.04 Server that runs

`Linux 4.4.0-187-generic #217-Ubuntu SMP Tue Jul 21 04:18:15 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`, all packages are very recent (I regularly perform standard updates). There is not much installed on that server: `apt list --installed | wc -l` yields `889` Packages,

and the filesystem has these partitions:

```
Filesystem                           Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev                                 2,0G     0  2,0G   0% /dev
tmpfs                                396M   26M  370M   7% /run
/dev/mapper/host--vg-root        45G  6,8G   36G  16% /
tmpfs                                2,0G   88K  2,0G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs                                5,0M     0  5,0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs                                2,0G     0  2,0G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs                                2,0G     0  2,0G   0% /run/shm
/dev/sda1                            472M  133M  315M  30% /boot
/dev/mapper/host--vgdata-data1  1,8T  824G  958G  47% /data1
tmpfs                                396M     0  396M   0% /run/user/1000
```

The system tries to convince me to upgrade to 18.04.5, but I am hesitant.
I'd like to upgrade for consistency reasons,  because that is the version that I have installed on a few other machines.

If the upgrade process fails I would be in trouble.

Anyone tried that specific upgrade ? (I'm asking because [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1230433/lvm-problem-after-upgrade-14-04-20-04) someone reports problems upgrading from 14.04 to 20.04. There are more posts like this.)

Comment: "I have an Ubuntu 16.04 Server". Generally I would advice against upgrading production servers. What I would advice: get a 2nd server and alternate between them: server 1 is the active server. server 2 you put the new OS on, set up your personal files. Check it and make it the new server 1 and the old server 1 becomes server 2. And you repeat that for the next OS.

Comment: ^^^^ Sounds like good advice when you have a server that is so critical that "you would get into trouble if it fails", and it's not possible to simply do a backup, reinstall a new server and get it up and running. And at some point you need to upgrade anyway, so you might as well be ahead of the situation.

Comment: You must *prepare* to handle release-upgrade problems, just like you would a home plumbing or painting project. Backups, handy install media, network access, testing environment, spare keyboard/monitor for servers, time for troubleshooting, and clear notes on how to rebuild the system from scratch. When you are *unprepared*, then small hiccups become crises. You can fail at almost anything...if you are unprepared.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having the root partition on LVM is fairly standard and shouldn't cause you any particular problems.

However, as the previous commenters have said already, there's always a chance of something going wrong during an upgrade (packaging bug, power outage, cosmic ray, etc) so you should be prepared.

Comment: Indeed, upgrade went through without problems; just a couple of config files that I've edited had to be changed (sysctl.conf, apache-config)